# Excluding particular category from displaying in specified areas

Tags: categories

Here's my site: http://tophistorie.pl/

I have one category that is responsible for displaying posts in slider (slider displays certain post if it has a specfic category assigned). The problem is that this category also shows up on my homepage and in single posts. Here's how it look like on my site:

Homepage - https://screenshots.firefox.com/5YuQDW4kFxEXuaQe/tophistorie.pl
Single post - https://screenshots.firefox.com/OCI1uBe0ZKUf20Km/tophistorie.pl

I would like to completely hide just this one particular category (Entertainment) from displaying in the areas shown above. Slash before or after this category also has to be removed.

Does anyone have any idea how can I do it?

Comment: And where should it be visible? Only in custom queries?

Comment: Nowhere :) This category exists only because slider requires that. This category page has to work, but its existense has to be hidden at least in these two areas shown above (I'm not sure if users can see it elsewhere)

Comment: And how do you get posts for that slider? What query do you use?

Comment: By adding it to this category

Comment: Its built into my theme. I just have to choose a specific category, its pretty common in WordPress world.

Comment: But I don't know your theme, so I don't know what query is used to select them, so I'm unable to write code that targets only that query ;)

Comment: To be honest I have no idea how to check it. Can you guide me how can I check it?